# What does Iron Maiden do?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

The [Iron Maiden](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/iron-maiden) skill description is...lacking.

> Gain Thorns.

How much thorns? What exactly does this passive do?

Comment: It probably scales by your level. Check your character statistics when you have it enabled.

Comment: That's the first time I've ever seen Blizzard provide such an obtuse description.

Comment: That feels like something that they intended to flesh out before the RoS release, but forgot. Weird.

Comment: at levle 70+ its supposed to be over 100k thorns

Comment: Such an awesome D2 reference though!

Comment: I have a legendary which can spawn a monster helper. It doesn't give any insight about how much damage he does, but I am fairly sure I saw him one-shot something which takes that char 2-3 hits to kill. So, add 1 more obtuse description.

Comment: I see this and get Iron Maiden (the band) stuck in my head. Am I too addicted to heavy metal? ._.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What exactly does this passive do?

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#crusader).

> Your Thorns has been increased by 50%.

---

**Pre [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#crusader) information.**

> What exactly does this passive do?

The passive gives you a static amount of thorns damage based on your current level and difficult level. You can't unlock [Iron Maiden](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/iron-maiden) until level 50. And you can't unlock a passive slot until level 10.

---

Here is what i have so far:

Assuming level 70. And assuming a base value of thorns 6102 at normal level and level 70.

You can multiply that base value by the Monster Health % gained from the increase in difficulty level. And you will get numbers that are VERY close to the numbers that show up on the passive for each of those difficulty levels. The "calculated value" column in my picture is `=6102*monsterHealth`. Difference is just the `actual value - calculated value`.

Here are my numbers:

[image]

---

> How much thorns?

At level 70 the passive says the following for each difficulty level:

- normal.......6102
- hard...........12205
- expert........19528
- master.......31245
- torment1....49992
- torment2....79987
- torment3....127978
- torment4....204765
- torment5....327625
- torment6....524200

Comment: those numbers are definately not correct.  It doesn't help that the in game tooltips are broken as well.  I think right now it only adds the 6000 thorns (normal level) no matter the difficulty.

Comment: Why do you think the in game tooltip for this skill is broken?

Comment: because everytime I hover over it on my crusader on torment 1 says it adds 49992 thorns but in my character sheet I see ~6000 thorns added.

Comment: That does not, necessarily, mean that the tooltip is wrong. It could be thorns from `Iron Maiden` are not calculated into the number you are seeing on your data sheet.

Comment: oh but I see that it adds 6000 thorns when I equip the passive and I lose 6000 thorns when I remove it, so its definately affecting my data sheet.

Comment: What level is your Crusader?

Comment: 70 (12 characters)

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip on Blizzard's site is somewhat misleading.  It's missing the X between the words, since it depends on your level.  I just hit level 10 with my Crusader, and it says, "Gain 204 Thorns" damage.  Not that I can select it, but that's what it says.

Levelling up to 11 didn't change that at all, so there's probably something else I'm missing.  Perhaps it only starts increasing at a specific level.

Comment: What difficulty level were you on when you checked that value when you hit level 10?

Answer (score -5):

Go to your game options, and turn on detailed tooltips. This will change the tool tips to describe precisely what the effect does. This is turned off by default, as the detailed tooltips are very technical, specifying things like "does 150% weapon damage as fire." In general, "thorns" seems to mean that any unit that attacks you takes damage. I infer this from my experiences where any equipment titled "of Thorns" or "Thorned" has a passive of "Ranged and Melee attackers take X damage."

Comment: If you look at [all the Crusader passives](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/) they already give detailed information, except for Iron Maiden. I already have detailed tooltips on. Thorns obviously returns damage; that's the whole point of the effect. You didn't actually say anything about what the particular skill in question *actually does*.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't help any, just trying to do what I can to assist a fellow gamer. I wold assume that it passively grants thorns, but I don't have access to the crusader.